# I am getting error An unexpected error occurred while running yarn add/install

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

```
yarn add v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-ethereumjs-util-5.2.1-a833f0e5fca7e5b361384dc76301a721f537bf65-integrity\\node_modules\\ethereumjs-util\\.yarn-metadata.json: Unexpected end of JSON input".
```

Comment: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/660 can you try this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 12):

```
yarn cache clean
```

this will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that something happened to your yarn package while you were installing another npm package. it's also possible that it was deleted or corrupted somehow. try re-installing it, will fix the problem:

```bash
# assuming you've installed it through the brew
brew reinstall yarn

# OR NPM
npm install -g yarn
```

Happy coding!

Comment: `yarn cache clean` did help me. re-installing worked for me!